# Why data tables are merging with other even after using 2 different binding tables in JSF

Tags: jsf, datatable, xhtml

For DataTable 1 and 2 getting data from same bean and binding table same bean with different names but is showing as only one data table.

```
            <h:dataTable  id="system" border="1" binding="#{activeSystemStatsBean.table}" rowClasses="evenRows,oddRows" rules="all"
             headerClass="standardTableHeader" styleClass="standardTable" value="#{activeSystemStatsBean.list}" var="active">
```

dataTable 2 code following

```
            <h:dataTable  id="callCount" border="1" binding="#{activeSystemStatsBean.callTable}" rowClasses="evenRows,oddRows" rules="all"
             headerClass="standardTableHeader" styleClass="standardTable" value="#{activeSystemStatsBean.callCountList}" var="calls">
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is the purpose of specifying a binding? You probably don't need to